# Linq performance issue with huge record set

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am writing a LINQ query and its performance is much slower than fetching from DB. Can you please give some idea how can I increase the performance.

```
cmbMedicines.DataSource = Lookup.Medicines
       .Where(d => d.DosageForm.Equals(cmbType.SelectedValue.ToString()))
       .AsParallel().ToList();
```

Here cmbMedicines is a Combobox and Lookup.Medicines is the List of Medicines and it has around 100K records.

Comment: Side note: I assume [lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is used as 100.000 ... Feel free to edit if my change is wrong...

Comment: What is the `AsParallel` doing here?  Is `Lookup.Medicines` a queryable interface?

Comment: `AsParallel` does not has any sense here.

Comment: Even if I remove it the performance is the same. I was just trying various methods.

Comment: `performance is much slower than fetching from DB`: you're going to have to be a lot more specific with that. What in the world does that even mean? Are you comparing apples and apples here (e.g. you ran the same statement with ADO)? Did you **look at the statement being generated to verify?**

Comment: I am using the Access DB and in the I am writing the simple select query with the filter condition which is same as LINQ query. And when I actually query the access DB and fetch the records is faster than the above linq query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var selectedVal = cmbType.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmbMedicines.DataSource = Lookup.Medicines.AsParallel()
      .Where(d => d.DosageForm.Equals(selectedVal)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

More info would be useful.  One thing I wonder about is the "Equals" call.  First is DosageForm a string?  I wonder if you created a string outside the Linq statement if it would be faster.  For example (assuming DosageForm is string):

```
var val = cmbType.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmbMedicines.DataSource = Lookup.Medicines
            .Where(d => d.DosageForm == val))
            .ToList();
```

Also I think that DataSource will accept and IEnumerable, so if you drop the ".ToList()" you might save a lot of time (if the query returns a lost of stuff).

SQL servers are highly optimized for this sort of thing so depending on the overhead required to transmit the data it might be difficult to beat.

Comment: and DosageForm is a String.

Comment: Sorry wrong must have been mistaken about the DataSource accepting IEnumerable.  Was the other suggestions helpful?

Comment: Hmmm sounds like it's still slow, perhaps adding back the AsParallel as shown by Mokchhya with my change will provide acceptable performance?

Comment: Is this causing the UI to hang while the datasource is being updated?  If so you might try doing the linq query on a separate thread, then set the datasource after everything is processed.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I love linq, it's not the solution to all humankind problems ...
Why would you like to have 100K objects in memory so you can then linq them, if you can have them in a database, and just query the database to get the results?

Use the database as it was supposed to be used, and use linq as it was supposed to be used ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Combobox data binding process also reduce the performance.
If it possible for you, you should use other control instead of the Combobox to handle a big data.

I assume that your users should know which madicine they want to select, so they could put a part of medicine name in search box. This just a choice, you may use TextBox (names **txtMedicines** in my sample code) with **AutoComplete** to search binding data when user enter some word to search in the list.

This is a sample code

```
private void InitializeMedicinesAutoComplete()
{
   var searchMed = Lookup.Medicines
       .Where(d => d.DosageForm.Equals(cmbType.SelectedValue.ToString())).ToList(); 

   var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
   foreach (var med in searchMed)
   {
      // **DisplayMemberText mean any field that you want to display in searching list
      source.Add(med.DisplayMemberText); 
   }
   txtMedicines.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
   txtMedicines.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
   txtMedicines.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
}

private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InitializeMedicinesAutoComplete();
}
```

I hope this will help.